# Textbox TextMode="Email" asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I tried to use text box with text mode="Email", but it only validate is the text with @ or not. I can still pass my text with ABC@ABC without any second level domain.

I still have to validate the string input by another validation/function to done this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" MaxLength="50" PlaceHolder="example@someone.com" runat="server" textMode="Email" /> =
<br/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailFormat" runat="server" Text="Please enter a valid Email" ToolTip="Please enter a valid Email" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationExpression="(\w)+@(\w)+.com(.(\w)+)*" ForeColor="Red"  />
```

Comment: text mode="Email" is an HTML5 feature and we cannot customize it. So you definitely need to write other validation code or use asp:RegularExpressionValidator (which you are doing in your code).

Comment: The reason that it validates this way is that `Someone@IP_Address` is a valid email address and with the introduction of IP6 Ip addresses don't have to include `.` at all so this is the only complete Email validation you can use. if you are willing to lose the very unusual IP emails then you can provide tighter validation on the more common ones but as a fit everywhere standard HTML5 can't do that

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to try Email Validation using regular expression in ASP.Net. I have below code for you which solve your problem.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextBox inputText"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailAddress" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
                        Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" resourceKey="revEmailAddress"
                        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="register"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button ID="lnkBtnRegister" runat="server" ValidationGroup="register"
                        CssClass="login-btn fl" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="lnkBtnRegister_Click" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="valsumRegister" resourceKey="valsumRegister" runat="server"
                    ShowSummary="false" ShowMessageBox="true" ValidationGroup="register" HeaderText="Please Provide..." />
```

Comment: so u mean textmode=email is not completed?

Comment: Please remove it because you already used Regular Expression.

Comment: because, if it can work well, i don need to create a custom regular expression. just want to find it out did it working or not

Comment: `TextMode="Email"` works only in .net framework 4.5 only. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/776764/Introducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @YuYenkan that depends on the definition of complete, are there any valid emails that it wont allow you to submit? NO in this regard it is complete. Are there any invalid emails that it will allow Yes but the same is true for any email validator that doesn't poll every DNS on the planet to check what domains are currently in use